# I want to .split a string which is tooo long

Tags: actionscript-3, split

**This is my string ,,,, please help [ i use action script 3 but you can answer in any lang']
I only want the names and id
**

*'{"data":[{"name":"fhfgdhg","id":"1324231864276217"},{"name":"fhfdhfh","id":"1197660730326224"},{"name":"fhdhfgh","id":"1131720603601900"},{"name":"fdhfdghfg","id":"610530709133257"},{"name":"dfghfdh","id":"580102228843815"},{"name":"fdhfhfh","id":"657695841092832"},{"name":"dhfhf","id":"1878237492447644"},{"name":"dfghfgdh","id":"358290074522881"},{"name":"fdhf","id":"199052413834818"},{"name":"dghfdgh","id":"107884723111778"}],
"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUldoTlJGTXVoOV9pUE54ZAklvNDc5YkRoWVRQYkE3T1pXcXNzeXJoN3I0QUt4ZAmlLVkxCanVYMzRzd3hUWTRZAdDNVQVI0YlpWT3pIZAjJXUHFvXzd6Q1BR",
"after":"QVFIUnQ1Wmgzb2E1VEhEV2xiTFIwYU10dkFQcUtaV2pQbVJNVlR5SWQ2T1NRMThsUUJXYi1IdklKdjl1NkkzZAmRSMTdESXd4bkJtMXZAXalViOEItUWhWaFFn"}},
"summary":{"total_count":1636}}'*

Comment: What do you want your output to be? and what have you tried?

Comment: i want the names and id only

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
$string = '{"data":[{"name":"fhfgdhg","id":"1324231864276217"},{"name":"fhfdhfh","id":"1197660730326224"},{"name":"fhdhfgh","id":"1131720603601900"},{"name":"fdhfdghfg","id":"610530709133257"},{"name":"dfghfdh","id":"580102228843815"},{"name":"fdhfhfh","id":"657695841092832"},{"name":"dhfhf","id":"1878237492447644"},{"name":"dfghfgdh","id":"358290074522881"},{"name":"fdhf","id":"199052413834818"},{"name":"dghfdgh","id":"107884723111778"}], "paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUldoTlJGTXVoOV9pUE54ZAklvNDc5YkRoWVRQYkE3T1pXcXNzeXJoN3I0QUt4ZAmlLVkxCanVYMzRzd3hUWTRZAdDNVQVI0YlpWT3pIZAjJXUHFvXzd6Q1BR", "after":"QVFIUnQ1Wmgzb2E1VEhEV2xiTFIwYU10dkFQcUtaV2pQbVJNVlR5SWQ2T1NRMThsUUJXYi1IdklKdjl1NkkzZAmRSMTdESXd4bkJtMXZAXalViOEItUWhWaFFn"}}, "summary":{"total_count":1636}}';
$string = json_decode($string);
foreach($string as $s) {
  foreach($s as $s2) {
   echo $s2->name;
   echo $s2->id;
  }
}
```